# javascript functions wait for data availability or variable not capable of handling huge data

Tags: javascript, function

forgive the trivial question but I am more used to C++ and Python code than javascript.

I have the following code from the THREE JS PLY loader:

```
var geometry;
      var scope = this;

      if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {

        geometry = isASCII(data) ? parseASCII(bin2str(data)) : parseBinary(data);

      } else {

        geometry = parseASCII(data);

      }



parse: function (data) {

      function isASCII(data) {

        var header = parseHeader(bin2str(data));
        return header.format === 'ascii';

      }

      function bin2str(buf) {

        var array_buffer = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < buf.byteLength; i++) {

          str += String.fromCharCode(array_buffer[i]); // implicitly assumes little-endian

        }

        return str;

      }
```

It works fine if I load a small ply file but browser crashes on very large one. I believe there are two "possible" issues:

1) on a large file the string str returned by the function bin2str(buf) might not be able to handle the parsing process

2) in the function isASCII(data) the line

```
parseHeader(bin2str(data));
```

crashes the browser as the bin2str(data) cannot return a proper value in time as the process is very memory consuming

I am using the conditional as i am not totally sure of what the problem is. Any suggestion and/or possible solution?

Thank you,

Dino

Comment: Not sure how you are intending to use the data, but have you considered Web Workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API You can have your function run in a separate thread that shouldn't crash the main window (browsers are single-threaded).

Comment: Hi Skyline, thank you for your answer. It sounded promising but I am finding difficult to use it. Web workers need to be independent pieces of javascript and cannot interact with the DOM. My problem is that I need to use the THREE JS library in my web worker (I don't know how to import it in Angular 2 yet) and when the worker has finished it should update the scene with the loaded geometry. It looks like Web Workers are not the solution but I am still investigating your suggestion. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I have adopted was to decimate my file using the free software MeshLab.

Hope this helps.

Dino